# export excel file does not open in server but in localhost excel file open correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel

I want to get Excel file report from my data in asp.net mvc ,
but when I am in Local host and run from my codes it get me a file correctly and file Open right .
but when I get codes in Server and I export Excel file ,after Download file , I click To Open , But It has Error that file format does not correct and does not open . I am very Confused . Please help me . my code :

```
public FileResult ExportOrders(string sortOrder, string title, string orderStatus
        , string sellerTrackCode, string paymentType, string settlementType, string sellerId, string excelDocumentId,
        string postmanId, string sellerCustomerName, string submittedDate, string fromSubmittedDate, string tillSubmittedDate,
        string fromDeliveredDate, string tillDeliveredDate, string fromPickUpDate, string tillPickUpDate, string fromId,
        string tillId, int? menuType, int? page, int? pageSize)
    {
        var query = _orderRepository.AsQueryable();
        var currentUser = User.Identity.GetUserName();

        if (currentUser != string.Empty)
        {
            var dbUser = _personRoleRepository.AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Person.UserName == currentUser);
            if (dbUser != null)
            {
                List<SellerCustomer> allSellerCustomers = new List<SellerCustomer>();
                var role = dbUser.Role;
                if (role.Title == "Seller")
                {
                    var seller = _sellerRepository.AsQueryable().First(x => x.PersonId == dbUser.PersonId);
                    query = query.Where(x => x.SellerId == seller.Id);
                }
            }
        }

        if (menuType == (int)MenuType.UnDoneOrders)
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.OrderStatus == (byte)OrderStatus.Submitted || x.OrderStatus == (byte)OrderStatus.PayedByUser ||
                    x.OrderStatus == (byte)OrderStatus.TransmitToPort);
            ViewBag.menuType = MenuType.UnDoneOrders;
        }

        if (menuType == (int)MenuType.OpenOrders)
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.OrderStatus == (byte)OrderStatus.WaitingForPostmanAssignment);
            ViewBag.menuType = MenuType.OpenOrders;
        }
        if (menuType == (int)MenuType.InProgressOrders)
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.PostmanId != null && x.OrderStatus != (int)OrderStatus.DeliverToCustomer
                                                             && x.OrderStatus != (int)OrderStatus.ReturnedOrder);
            ViewBag.menuType = MenuType.InProgressOrders;
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(submittedDate))
        {
            DateTime date = CalendarHelper.GetGregorianDateTime(submittedDate);
            query = query.Where(s => s.SubmittedDate.Equals(date));
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(orderStatus))
        {
            var status = (byte)EnumsConverter.GetValueFromDescription<OrderStatus>(orderStatus);
            query = query.Where(s => s.OrderStatus.Equals(status));
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
        {
            query = query.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(title));
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sellerTrackCode))
        {
            query = query.Where(s => s.SellerTrackCode.Contains(sellerTrackCode));
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(paymentType))
        {
            var type = (byte)EnumsConverter.GetValueFromDescription<PaymentType>(paymentType);

            query = query.Where(s => s.PaymentType.Equals(type));
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(settlementType))
        {
            var settlement = (byte)EnumsConverter.GetValueFromDescription<SettlementType>(settlementType);
            query = query.Where(s => s.SettlementType.Equals(settlement));
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sellerId))
        {
            var selId = Convert.ToInt32(sellerId);
            query = query.Where(s => s.SellerId == selId);
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(excelDocumentId))
        {
            var selId = Convert.ToInt32(excelDocumentId);
            query = query.Where(s => s.ExcelDocumentId == selId);
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sellerCustomerName))
        {
            query = query.Where(s => s.SellerCustomerName.Contains(sellerCustomerName));
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(postmanId))
        {
            var selId = Convert.ToInt32(postmanId);
            query = query.Where(s => s.PostmanId == selId);
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fromSubmittedDate))
        {
            var gregor = CalendarHelper.GetGregorianDate(fromSubmittedDate);
            query = query.Where(s => s.SubmittedDate >= gregor);
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tillSubmittedDate))
        {
            var gregor = CalendarHelper.GetGregorianEndDate(tillSubmittedDate);
            query = query.Where(s => s.SubmittedDate <= gregor);
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fromPickUpDate))
        {
            var gregor = CalendarHelper.GetGregorianDateTime(fromPickUpDate);
            query = query.Where(s => s.PickUpDate >= gregor);
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tillPickUpDate))
        {
            var gregor = CalendarHelper.GetGregorianDateTime(tillPickUpDate);
            query = query.Where(s => s.PickUpDate <= gregor);
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fromId))
        {
            var x = Convert.ToInt64(fromId);
            query = query.Where(s => s.Id >= x);
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tillId))
        {
            var x = Convert.ToInt64(tillId);
            query = query.Where(s => s.Id <= x);
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fromDeliveredDate))
        {
            var gregor = CalendarHelper.GetGregorianDate(fromDeliveredDate);
            query = query.Where(s => s.DeliveredDate >= gregor);
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tillDeliveredDate))
        {
            var gregor = CalendarHelper.GetGregorianEndDate(tillDeliveredDate);
            query = query.Where(s => s.DeliveredDate <= gregor);
        }

        sortOrder = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? SortKeys.PickupDateDesc : sortOrder;

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case SortKeys.SubmittedDate:
                query = query.OrderBy(x => x.SubmittedDate).ThenBy(x => x.Id);
                break;
            case SortKeys.SubmittedDateDesc:
                query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.SubmittedDate).ThenBy(x => x.Id);
                break;
            case SortKeys.PickupDate:
                query = query.OrderBy(x => x.PickUpDate).ThenBy(x => x.Id);
                break;
            case SortKeys.PickupDateDesc:
                query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.PickUpDate).ThenBy(x => x.Id);
                break;
            case SortKeys.OrderStatus:
                query = query.OrderBy(x => x.OrderStatus).ThenBy(x => x.Id);
                break;
            case SortKeys.OrderStatusDesc:
                query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.OrderStatus).ThenBy(x => x.Id);
                break;
            case SortKeys.Title:
                query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Title).ThenBy(x => x.Id);
                break;
            case SortKeys.TitleDesc:
                query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Title).ThenBy(x => x.Id);
                break;
            case SortKeys.SellerTrackCode:
                query = query.OrderBy(x => x.SellerTrackCode).ThenBy(x => x.Id);
                break;
            case SortKeys.SellerTrackCodeDesc:
                query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.SellerTrackCode).ThenBy(x => x.Id);
                break;
            case SortKeys.SellerId:
                query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Seller.StoreName).ThenBy(x => x.Id);
                break;
            case SortKeys.SellerIdDesc:
                query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Seller.StoreName).ThenBy(x => x.Id);
                break;
            case SortKeys.SellerCustomerName:
                query = query.OrderBy(x => x.SellerCustomerName).ThenBy(x => x.Id);
                break;
            case SortKeys.SellerCustomerNameDesc:
                query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.SellerCustomerName).ThenBy(x => x.Id);
                break;
            case SortKeys.PostmanId:
                query = query.OrderBy(x => x.PostmanId).ThenBy(x => x.Id);
                break;
            case SortKeys.PostmanIdDesc:
                query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.PostmanId).ThenBy(x => x.Id);
                break;
        }

        var orders = query.ToList();

        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/"), "orderExcel.xlsx");

        if (orders.Count > 0)
        {
            using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(path)))
            {
                var ws = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "sheet1");
                if (ws != null)
                {
                    excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Delete(ws);
                }
                excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("sheet1");

                var workSheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                workSheet.Cells.Style.HorizontalAlignment = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
                workSheet.DefaultColWidth = 15;
                workSheet.Column(2).Width = 20;
                workSheet.Column(4).Width = 20;
                workSheet.Column(5).Width = 30;
                workSheet.Column(6).Width = 20;
                workSheet.Column(7).Width = 20;
                workSheet.Column(8).Width = 20;
                workSheet.Column(11).Width = 30;
                workSheet.Column(12).Width = 30;
                workSheet.Column(13).Width = 40;
                workSheet.Cells["I1:J1"].Merge = true;
                workSheet.View.RightToLeft = true;

                workSheet.Cells.Style.WrapText = true;

                workSheet.Cells[1, 9].Value = "هزینه های قابل پرداخت گیرنده";
                workSheet.Cells[2, 1].Value = "ردیف";
                workSheet.Cells[2, 2].Value = "شماره ارجاع";
                workSheet.Cells[2, 3].Value = "نوع مرسوله";
                workSheet.Cells[2, 4].Value = "نام گیرنده";
                workSheet.Cells[2, 5].Value = "آدرس گیرنده";
                workSheet.Cells[2, 6].Value = "شماره همراه گیرنده";
                workSheet.Cells[2, 7].Value = "تلفن گیرنده";
                workSheet.Cells[2, 8].Value = "تاریخ دریافت سفارش";
                workSheet.Cells[2, 9].Value = "وجه کالا";
                workSheet.Cells[2, 10].Value = "هزینه حمل";
                workSheet.Cells[2, 11].Value = "وضعیت سفارش";
                workSheet.Cells[2, 12].Value = "توضیحات";
                workSheet.Cells[2, 13].Value = "کد رهگیری";

                for (var index = 0; index < orders.Count; index++)
                {
                    var order = orders[index];
                    workSheet.Cells[index + 3, 1].Value = index + 1;
                    workSheet.Cells[index + 3, 2].Value = order.SellerTrackCode;
                    workSheet.Cells[index + 3, 3].Value = order.Title;
                    workSheet.Cells[index + 3, 4].Value = order.SellerCustomerName ?? string.Empty;
                    workSheet.Cells[index + 3, 5].Value = order.OrderAddress;
                    workSheet.Cells[index + 3, 6].Value = order.Mobile;
                    workSheet.Cells[index + 3, 7].Value = order.Tel;
                    workSheet.Cells[index + 3, 8].Value = order.PickUpDate.GetPersianDate();
                    workSheet.Cells[index + 3, 9].Value = order.OrderValue;
                    workSheet.Cells[index + 3, 10].Value = order.DeliveryCost;
                    workSheet.Cells[index + 3, 11].Value = EnumsConverter.GetDescriptionFromValue((OrderStatus)order.OrderStatus);
                    workSheet.Cells[index + 3, 12].Value = order.Description;
                    workSheet.Cells[index + 3, 13].Value = order.Id;
                }
                excelPackage.Save();
            }
        }
        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        string fileName = "orderExcel.xlsx";
        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: It may be a Globalization thing.  What is the hosting server location?

Comment: hosting server is in Iran...

Comment: What is the exact error and what line does it occur?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to handle your UTF-8 characters:

```
byte[] fileBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(File.ReadAllText(path));
```

Comment: Can try me edited one? Should be the problem with encoding, i think.